# Srctool.exe returns -1 error code in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We just set up TFS 11 for the first time.  Running a gated check in, it succeeds but returns this message:

> 'srctool.exe' returned an unexpected exit code: '-1'.  An error
>   occurred when opening a file "CustomDllName.dll": Assembly
>   "CustomDllName.dll" is not a valid .NET assembly and will be skipped
>   for analysis.

Well, it's right: that file is a legacy Visual Basic 6 DLL that we don't have much control over.  It's included in the project for COM access to some of the methods.

Is there a way to instruct srctool.exe/TFS to skip that file when doing the inspection?  Or another way to attack this?

Comment: You could open the Build Process Template and edit the arguments for the SrcTool executable, I suspect (haven't checked) that it will take $(OutDir)\**\*.dll or something very similar. And change that to something that somehow excludes your Dll. Or you could not make the old COM dll part of your build output folder.

Comment: Yes - it looks to be a known issue that the team is addressing as well.

Comment: @EdBlankenship Thanks.  Do you have an ETA, or link for more information on this?  Is there a temporary workaround or hotfix?

Comment: @msigman Yes - Duat has more information below about the workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is the solution that ultimately worked for me

A member of the TFS 11 team at Microsoft mentioned to me that the problem is due to a change in behavior that the Windows 8 team made to the `srctool.exe` tool.

By copying this file from the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279) (WinDBG) toolkit and overriding the one included in TFS 11 Beta, I was able to successfully run a build without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a srctool.exe error from the shipped IndexSources activity? srctool.exe in this activity does one thing, which is to list the source files information in the pdb. I am not a srctool expert so I don't know why it fails in this case. I do know that srctool.exe has some behavioral changes in version 11, most of those are fixes from the previous version.

There is a workaround which requires udpating the build template. It is not very nice but it works. Srctool.exe is run (inside IndexSources activity) for each pdb file in the SymbolFiles collection. Now that you know which pdb fails, you can update the build template to add a R[emoveFromCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647801.aspx) activity before the IndexSources activity that remove the troubled pdb from the SymbolFiles collection. This is by far the most straightforward workaround I can think of.

Alternatively, you can edit FindMatchingFiles activity's search pattern to exclude the pdb files you don't want to have sources indexed.

Based on the error message you got, it doesn't seem to be related to the known issue Ed mentioned. We fixed this issue for the next release, so if it's related, it should be fixed :-)

Let me know if you have any issue with VS11 Beta around the build templates.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you're on the right track.  I wasn't able to find a pattern that would cause `FindMatchingFiles` to exclude a file.  Can you suggest one?  Also I couldn't get `RemoveFromCollection` to work because it expects a Collection input but `symbolFiles` is just an IEnumerable.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately even after removing the legacy DLL from the project, the same message is returned: 'srctool.exe' returned an unexpected exit code: '-1'.